# Meaning of "tint your wing" in the song Burning of Auchindoun

Tags: meaning, lyrics, scottish-english

In the Scottish folk song [Burning of Auchindoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auchindoun_Castle#%22The_Burning_of_Auchindoun%22_song) appears the following lines:

> Crawing, crawing, for a' your crouse crawin'
> Ye burnt yer crop an **tint** your wings an oor before the dawnin

I'm interested in the meaning behind these lines, particularly the word "tint".

My current hunch on the meaning is that despite all their crouse crawin' (confidence and loud talk?), they (Earl of Huntly's people) metaphorically burnt their own crops (in the Corvid anatomical sense of the word) and tint ([variation of tyne meaning to lose, or lose your footing "tint my feet"](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/tyne)) their wings, implying they were defeated.

Does this seem like a correct interpretation?

Comment: We need someone who is familiar with Scottish folk song terminology to interpret that.

Comment: https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/tyne

Comment: The structure of the song is complex, seeming to have two speakers, but yes it seems to be saying that by burning the castle, they've incurred the wrath of Huntly and doomed themselves (the Wikipedia article linked in the question mentions the tangled story of attack and revenge, both in folk tale and fact). This is literary criticism and history, not really on topic for ELU.

Answer (score -1):

[This site](https://sangstories.webs.com/auchindoon.htm) concurs with your interpretation and offers definitions:

```
Crawin: crowing like a cock, boasting
Crop: an internal seed-pouch in
Crouse: arrogant, bold
Fear: frighten
Heid: behead
Tint: lost
```

Comment: You have failed to correctly reference material written by others. [Please review our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and edit your post accordingly